# Iframe - how to change iframe height automatically?

Tags: iframe

I need to change height of an iframe, which is changing his weight.
For example, iframe is a form, which is like 500px height, but when user click on smt, it changes size to for example 800px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to both the origin and the request file, my suggestion is to use this library that works REALLY good.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Be sure to read all the documentation tho, cause it may require some setup

Comment: I have got access just to the origin file.

Comment: Well to change the height, the iframe should send something to the page that is going to render it. If the page doesn't catch what the iframe sends, there's no way the iframe knows the exact height of the content, especially if this could change..